# Java Regex to select starting and ending quotes in a string

Tags: java, regex

I am inserting a string into a database and need to eliminate the beginning and ending quotes in the string.

I am using:

```
String a = rows[0].replaceAll("^\"", "").replaceAll("\"$", "");`
```

This gives me: `"134432534"23"` => `134432534"23` but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Will there always be quotes around your string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really do not see how your call to replace is typically bad here, but you could simplify this.

```
String a = rows[0].replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
```

To remove the **first** character and **last** character from the string, considering they are always quotes, use..

```
String a = rows[0].substring(1, rows[0].length()-1);
```